# "It is not always true that he ... " and "It is not true that he always" have the same meaning?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, negation, logic

> He like to plays outside on a fine day, but sometimes plays games at
>   home.

I would like to describe this using "always", but am confused on whether which of the followings is better:

> 1. It is not always true that he plays outside on a fine day.
> 2. It is not true that he always plays outside on a fine day.

Do both have the same meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are similar, but not the same. "It's not always true that he..." means he does something most of the time, but not always. "It's not true that he always..." means somebody may have claimed that he always does something, but that's not true. It doesn't say anything about how often after than "not always". He might do this thing most of the time, often, occasionally, rarely or never.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the way you want to put it. Both are grammatically correct and convey similar meanings.

Comment: I believe the entirety of the answer to this question is explaining how "the way you put it" affects it.